# Browser recognising non-touch screen as a touchscreen

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, multiple-monitors, browser, touchscreen

I have recently replaced the primary screen in my triple-monitor arrangement with a touchscreen. Set-up worked like a dream on connecting without the need to change any settings.

However, I notice that since adding the touchscreen to the setup, my Chrome browser displays websites optimised for touch (mostly the differences are minor like items in drop-down menus are now much more spaced out) regardless of which monitor the browser is open on.

I rarely open my browser on the touchscreen. Is there a way to set it so that Chrome knows which monitor is open on, so that it knows when it is not running on the touchscreen? Failing that, is there a way to manually turn off the touch-optimisation of websites in the browser?

Answer (score 2):

You can turn off touch events entirely by doing the following:

1. Go to `chrome://flags`
2. Find the "Touch Events API" setting
3. Select "Disabled" in the dropdown

**Further Reading:** http://ccm.net/faq/40811-google-chrome-how-to-disable-touch-input